# How to implement custom pagination in Laravel?

Tags: php, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to implement my own pagination links while still using the built-in Laravel Paginator. My question is, how do I go about overriding a specific function in the Paginator class.

> > http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Pagination.Paginator.html#171-192

I am trying to change the return link in the getUrl () function. Would creating a class extension, then overriding the function inside of the new class, and loading it inside start/global.php

Is there a better way to override the core?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overriding, you can just create a new presenter for the pagination.

Within your views directory create a `slider.php` file. Then in your views config (app/config/views.php) change the value `paginator::slider` to `slider`.

Within your new file created as `slider.php` put the following:

```
<?php
    $presenter = new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter($paginator);
?>

<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can fully customize it and your own needs, this one works for me with Twitter Bootstrap 3.

---

For more information, check this thread: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2215

Answer (score 0):

Now they enabled that in config file: app/config/pagination.php
Go there and set the configuration variable the the corresponding one.